# How to make DataGridViewLinkColumn underline and change background color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I have a DataGridViewLinkColumn.How can I make the header(row = -1) as underline and change it's background color

```
var WarningsColumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn
            {

                Name = @"Warnings",
                HeaderText = @"Warnings",
                DataPropertyName = @"WarningsCount",
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells,               
                ReadOnly = true
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add custom code to a `CellPainting` event handler like this:

```
 Point spot;
 private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (e.CellBounds.Contains(spot))//Mouse over cell
            {
                PaintCellBackground(e.Graphics, Color.Red, e.CellBounds);
            }
            else //Mouse leave cell
            {
                PaintCellBackground(e.Graphics, Color.Green, e.CellBounds);
            }
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(){Alignment=StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            Font f = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), f, new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor), e.CellBounds, sf);
        }
    } 
 private void PaintCellBackground(Graphics g, Color c, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Rectangle topHalf = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Width, rect.Height / 2);
        Rectangle bottomHalf = new Rectangle(rect.Left, topHalf.Bottom, rect.Width, topHalf.Height);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, c)), topHalf);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), bottomHalf);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, rect, Color.Gray, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
                                         Color.Gray, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
                                         Color.Gray, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
                                         Color.Gray, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
    //Reset spot when mouse leave
    private void dataGridView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spot = Point.Empty;
    }
    //Update spot when mouse move 
    private void dataGridView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        spot = e.Location;
    }
```

It looks not good but it can help you get started, I think the default background is better. If so, you just need to call: `e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);`

## UPDATE

The custom painting should be applied on DoubleBuffered control. So I think you should create your own custom DataGridView like this (it's just a little more code):

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView {
    public CustomDataGridView(){
       DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm.. if i donot want to have the background color then what to do? I have to do it for (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == 2). So if i comment e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.CellBounds);
, the cell is coming and white and elevated.

Comment: sorry..but i didnot get where to call the e.Graphics.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true); for getting the default background  in your code

Comment: Please see my Updated code. I think you may want to accept the Grant Winney's answer. His answer is the best for case all the column headers have the same style. Thanks!

Comment: Remove all the if() under `e.Handled = true` and insert the line `e.Graphics.PaintBackground(...)` there.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar please un-accept my answer and accept the Grant Winney's answer, I think his answer is the best now. I don't mind anything. However, I think my answer is something you can use for customizing a datagridview in another case. :))) again I don't mind so please do so.

Comment: Hi Sir, it is throwing exception 'System.Drawing.Graphics' does not contain a definition for 'PaintBackground' and no extension method 'PaintBackground' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Graphics' could be found

Comment: oh sorry, that's my mistake, that's `e.PaintBackground(...)`, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
    = new DataGridViewCellStyle {BackColor = Color.Yellow, Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Underline)};
```

From the MSDN reference on [DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersdefaultcellstyle.aspx):

> If visual styles are enabled and EnableHeadersVisualStyles is set to true, all header cells except the TopLeftHeaderCell are painted using the current theme and the ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle values are ignored.

So you can set it to `False` and then override the defaults, and then you'll end up with something like this *(quick and dirty test to make sure it works)*:

[image]

**Edit:**

To apply a style to a single column, use this instead *(you'll want to put this after the code where you set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`):*

```
dataGridView1.Columns["your_column_name"].HeaderCell.Style
    = new DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor = Color.Yellow, Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Underline) };
```

[image]

Comment: which event i have to write this

Comment: But I need to do it for a particular column...RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == 2..if i do in the constructor, then the effect will be for all the columns

Comment: +1, this is best for setting all the column headers. I didn't think of this. may be this should be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Great - I love painting myself too much so that I didn't try finding out if there is something done for me. Love it. Thanks.