# C# Winforms DataGridViewLinkColumn remove underline dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, underline

I have a DataGridView with one of the columns of type DataGridViewLinkColumn. I need to remove the underline from the text of all the rows under that column on certain criteria. How can I do that Dynamically in the code?

Please suggest me some workarounds. Thanks!

Comment: There is an older question with opposite requirements. Suggested solution might work for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995775/how-to-make-datagridviewlinkcolumn-underline-and-change-background-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, modify according to your cases...

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in  dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
      foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
      {
        DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = cell as DataGridViewLinkCell;
        if(linkCell != null)
        {
          linkCell.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;
        }
      }
}
```